# Static functions in action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a application and it is used by multiple users at a same time . i wanted to use a common function say for example number format

```
  public class CustomFormat
  {
     public static function funt(val:int,prec:int):int
     {
        // return val with formatting along with prec
     }
  }
```

As `static` functions are attached to classes not to the instances .

now assume the case when two user's call that `CustomFormat.funt(2,2);` & `CustomFormat.funt(3,3);` at same time  how this will act . i guess there might me issue in result's . to try still i did not implement this , so any suggestion's , if this has issue then i need create an object for each request or anything else i need to do

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misconception of what an swf based application is.

Every user that loads your app will have an unique instance of the app: it is a **client** app that runs inside your user's **browser**. It's not possible that several users could be accessing at the same time to your static function because it's not running that way (i.e. inside a server).

And considering that your app is single threaded (you're not using [AS3 Workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)) each call to the static function will be executed in order.

In other case, you should consider your static function as a shared resource, so you will have to implement concurrent mechanisms in order to assure a correct access of it.